# I would like to implement only zoom in feature on uiscrollview in iphone sdk.Is it possible to do this?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

I would like to implement only zoom in feature on uiscrollview in iphone sdk.Is it possible to do this?

I am using bellow code

```
{
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 700, 510)];
   scrollView.delegate = self;
   scrollView.ScrollEnabled=YES;
   scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(700, 510);
   scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;
   scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
   scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1;
   scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2;
   [scrollView addSubview:portrateSlideImage];
   [portSlideContainer addSubview:scrollView];
```

}

And using uiscrollview delagte

```
-(UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return portrateSlideImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. May be this would help you.

Remove the line from the code where you are setting maximum scale of scroll view

```
{
   scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 700, 510)];
   scrollView.delegate = self;
   scrollView.ScrollEnabled=YES;
   scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(700, 510);
   scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;         //edited again
   scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
   scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1;
   scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2;                  //edited again
   [scrollView addSubview:portrateSlideImage];
   [portSlideContainer addSubview:scrollView];
}
```

And add this function

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale
{
   scrollView.minimumZoomScale = scale;
}
```

It won't allow you to `zoom out` . Just zoom in

Comment: after changing code according to your suggestion code work fine but after zoom-in twice it just hang nothing happens.

Comment: I have made some corrections in the code. Please change those two things and try again. Sure you'll be able to do it this time :)

Comment: Still it  not working...Can u provide any tutorial which can help me

Comment: I can send you the demo application of this. if you want

Comment: my email id is dheerajrathore3002@yahoo.co.in or at rathoredheeraj7@gmail.com

Comment: Okay...hey after using my code....are you able to do the zoom for 2 levels ??? Also, does it allow you to zoom out for these two levels ?

Comment: I have sent you an email containing the demo project on your yahoo email id. Please check it out :)

Comment: No for the two level it is working fine....but after that it neither zoom-in nor zoom-out...

Comment: o..o How would it zoom-in or zoom-out after level 2 if you already described its maximum scale to "2"???? If you want to make it work for more levels then please set the values for the parameter "maximumZoomScale" of srollview to "7" or more. Definately, it'll work. I have used "7" as maximum limit in my demo project. Happy Coding :)