# How can I zoom a UIScrollview to a fixed point?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, uikit

I am creating a control for showing the timeline. Initially , it should show the year. When zooming in and the `zoomScale` reached a specific value, it will show the value of the individual months, and In the next zoom level, it should show the real values for the individual days.

I have creatd a `scrollview` and added the `layers` (for showing the month/year values) to this. After overriding the pinch guesture, I am able to do the zooming (*Normal UIScrollview zooming*). But I need to zoom it to a particular point. ie, Suppose i am zooming January, I need to keep it in the same position(*for creating an effect like moving inside of January*). Any suggestions to achieve this?

Is my way is currect? else please help me to start this.

Comment: u mean scrollView zoom at specific size ???

Comment: why don't you try the `-zoomToRect:animated:` method?

Answer (score 3):

Use This bellow method for your requirement,

```
- (void)zoomToRect:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated
```

just call this above method with your selected frame or point , like if select January then just take the point ( position) of january button or view and just call above method with that frame..

for more information see this link [UIScrollView_Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)

i hope this helpful to you...

Comment: I am not using the default UIScrollview zoom. I am resizing the layers in pinch guesture for reatsining the clarity of the text.Please see the code below for zooming. [CATransaction begin];
        [CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions]; 
        tmpLayer.frame = 'CGRectMake(i*layerWidthOnPinch*recognizer.scale,tmpLayer.frame.origin.y,layerWidthOnPinch*recognizer.scale, tmpLayer.frame.size.height);
        [tmpLayer setNeedsDisplay];
        [CATransaction commit];  eventScroll.contentOffset = CGPointMake(500, 0);

Comment: try this may be you get some idea from that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536555/i-would-like-to-implement-only-zoom-in-feature-on-uiscrollview-in-iphone-sdk-is

Comment: and this one is also.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150642/max-min-scale-of-pinch-zoom-in-uipinchgesturerecognizer-iphone-ios i just get some idea from this at one time for PichGesture.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150642/max-min-scale-of-pinch-zoom-in-uipinchgesturerecognizer-iphone-ios

Answer (score 2):

Here’s what it looks like:

```
@implementation UIScrollView (ZoomToPoint)

- (void)zoomToPoint:(CGPoint)zoomPoint withScale: (CGFloat)scale animated: (BOOL)animated
{
    //Normalize current content size back to content scale of 1.0f
    CGSize contentSize;
    contentSize.width = (self.contentSize.width / self.zoomScale);
    contentSize.height = (self.contentSize.height / self.zoomScale);

    //translate the zoom point to relative to the content rect
    zoomPoint.x = (zoomPoint.x / self.bounds.size.width) * contentSize.width;
    zoomPoint.y = (zoomPoint.y / self.bounds.size.height) * contentSize.height;

    //derive the size of the region to zoom to
    CGSize zoomSize;
    zoomSize.width = self.bounds.size.width / scale;
    zoomSize.height = self.bounds.size.height / scale;

    //offset the zoom rect so the actual zoom point is in the middle of the rectangle
    CGRect zoomRect;
    zoomRect.origin.x = zoomPoint.x - zoomSize.width / 2.0f;
    zoomRect.origin.y = zoomPoint.y - zoomSize.height / 2.0f;
    zoomRect.size.width = zoomSize.width;
    zoomRect.size.height = zoomSize.height;

    //apply the resize
    [self zoomToRect: zoomRect animated: animated];
}

@end
```

Looking at it, it should be pretty straightforward to figure out how it works. If you see anything wrong with it, let me know in the comments.
Thanks :)

source: http://www.tim-oliver.com/2012/01/14/zooming-to-a-point-in-uiscrollview/

Comment: I am not using the default UIScrollview zoom. I am resizing the layer in pich guester for retain the text clarity.

Comment: I'm working with this code. It works, but something works incorrect. I have Scale 3.0, and when i`m trying to zoomToRect - the center of content rect is wrong.

Comment: Oh wow! That's my blog post there! Thank you so much for crediting me! However, Nicolas is correct. When I was trying to do some more complex zooming with it, I discovered the origin calculation is off if you're not zooming in from the minimum scale value.

As a result, I just finished implementing a new version of this category. See if this one helps! :) https://gist.github.com/TimOliver/71be0a8048af4bd86ede

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem,
I was having a world map image, & i wanted to zoom the map to certain location, India
This is how i fixed it.
I found out the position of India, in terms of CGRect(X,Y) [CGRect(500,300)]
& following code in DidLoad

```
    [self.scrollViewForMap setZoomScale:2.0 animated:YES]; //for zooming
    _scrollViewForMap.contentOffset = CGPointMake(500,300); //for location
```

This solved my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)pinchDetected:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

if([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    // Reset the last scale, necessary if there are multiple objects with different scales
    lastScale = [gestureRecognizer scale];
}

if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ||
    [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

    CGFloat currentScale = [[[gestureRecognizer view].layer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.scale"] floatValue];

    // Constants to adjust the max/min values of zoom
    const CGFloat kMaxScale = 2.2;
    const CGFloat kMinScale = 0.64;

    CGFloat newScale = 1 -  (lastScale - [gestureRecognizer scale]);
    newScale = MIN(newScale, kMaxScale / currentScale);
    newScale = MAX(newScale, kMinScale / currentScale);
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformScale([[gestureRecognizer view] transform], newScale, newScale);
    [gestureRecognizer view].transform = transform;

    [gestureRecognizer setScale:1.0];

    lastScale = [gestureRecognizer scale];  // Store the previous scale factor for the next pinch gesture call
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me (**Swift 4**):

```
func zoomIn(with gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer?) {
    guard let location = gestureRecognizer?.location(in: gestureRecognizer?.view)

    let rect = CGRect(x: location.x, y: location.y, width: 0, height: 0)
    scrollView.zoom(to: rect, animated: true)
}
```

Or in other words creating a `CGRect` with zero width and height will cause the `UIScrollView` to zoom to the rects `origin` at `maximumZoomScale`